# seaborn subplot x-axis labels not rotating

Tags: seaborn, subplot, axis-labels

I'm trying  to show 2 subplots with x-axis labels rotated 90 degrees.  The first subplot's labels for some reason are not rotating.  Can anyone let me know what I'm missing?  Thanks!

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharey=True, figsize=(20,10))
fig.suptitle('Top and Bottom Countries by Rating')
plt.xticks(rotation=90)

sns.barplot(data=top_df, y='rating', x='bean_origin', ax=ax[0], palette="Blues_d")
ax[0].set_title('Top 10 Countries by Avg Rating')

sns.barplot(data=bottom_df, y='rating', x='bean_origin', ax=ax[1], palette="Reds_d")
ax[1].set_title('Bottom 10 Countries by Avg Rating')

plt.show()
```

[Link to chart image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/joM0g.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

**1. Call this AFTER plotting:** if 1 time not enough, try to add it after each plotting

```
sns.barplot('BLA BLA')
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
```

Otherwise try one of these solutions below:

**2.** :

```
fig.autofmt_xdate(rotation=90)
```

**3.**

```
labels = ['One', 'Two', 'Three'] #your labels
ax.set_xticks([1, 2, 3]) #your coord
ax.set_xticklabels(labels, rotation=90)
```

**4.**

```
ax.tick_params(axis='x', labelrotation=90)
```

*If none above works, provide full code.*

**Note:** IMO, 45° is better :)

Comment: Option 2 worked.  And I opted for 45 degrees.  Thank you!  :D